# Window Vista cannot create new folder, note, etc when right click and recent items forever empty after crashes

Tags: windows-vista, crash, checksum

Basically my computer crashes and after I reboot I got a checksum error, so I reboot again and these problems appears:
1):Unable to create new folder, notes, zip file,etc. (when I right click in desktop the extension from "new" is empty)

2):My recent items/file is always empty, start menu also do not display list of recently open programs

3):Any file put into Recycle Bin are instantly deleted

Anyone have any ideal why is this happening? Any solution to these problems? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what happens? Do you get a bugcheck or an Explorer crash?